# Google Drive API: Is it necessary to be logged in to perform create, delete, etc?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

Have been working through the docs but can't reconcile some things I clearly don't understand. Javascript on client side.

```
gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: API_KEY,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        scope: SCOPES
      })
```

used as per the docs

scopes have been set to either `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` or `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/somestringoflettersannumbersanddashes-?usp=sharing`

But am trying to avoid needing to log in, especially as the latter scope has full editing permissions enabled and does seem to be able to access the folder.

`gapi.client.drive.files.list({q:string,fields:string})` is able to generate a list, but `gapi.client.drive.files.create` and `delete({fileId:someid})` return a `401 error - login required`.

I don't know where I'm going wrong and the docs make it painfully UNclear what the requirements are, etc, why accessing the folder list seems to work while doing anything to it seems blocked off.

Or maybe I'm missing a parameter, who knows, it's a mystery. Can anybody tell me if I am doing something wrong with the calls or if, in the end, a user needs to be logged in to their google account to make changes.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, when I saw your question for the first time, I understood that you asked whether, in order to use create and delete file methods, it is required to log in to a Google account.

Comment: But from `was actually about generating tokens on my own app's server (no Web Apps) to be sent to a client device to be used to access a Drive, or is the token registered only for one device at one location?`, I noticed that I misunderstood your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In this case, my answer is not useful. So I have to delete my answer. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: That's a pity, it could have been useful for someone else with a related use-case. I also don't discount the possibility that I will use Web Apps - I just need to consider all of the possibilities and limitations with it. Don't worry about your English, keep practising, be positive that you WILL know it if you keep working with it - just like with programming :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that I misunderstood your question again. I would like to study more. If your issue was resolved, when you post it as an answer, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue. By the way, when you use Web Apps, this information might be useful. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you're trying to avoid logging in? To authorise the app you have to enter your credentials at some point, even if it's just the once the first time. Do you have a more full code? Have you downloaded your credentials successfully and have a token for authentication?

Comment: It's more in the way that providing a link to a folder to another person can grant them access to it with editing privileges. I can pull pull data with this scope (no logging in needed) but am unable to make changes to the folder.

Comment: I really don't undetstand what you're trying to do. You can't make changes to any file or folder if you're not logged in, even if the permissions of the file/folder are public. You have to perform the action on behalf of a user if you want to make some kind of change.

Comment: That does make sense, but I thought to view a file (the normal way, not via the API) you'd also need to be logged in to your own account, but maybe I'm wrong? It thought then that the API allowed this not-logged-in access.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I think your misunderstanding is incorrect. Being authenticated as a user is the only way of editing a file/folder, even if the file is publically editable. The change has to be attested to someone and for that the API needs to know who you are.

This is different to the UI where you can edit a public-facing document when not logged in.